# Deserialize a file with only methods

Tags: java, json, serialization, reflection, deserialization

I need to serialize/deserialize a Java file containing only methods calls into a JSON file.
I don't know if it's possible. I looked for it and I found mentions of the Reflection API.

This is the first time I've looked into JSON and would like to know if it's possible and if I'm on the right path.

Comment: Hi Jeremy! First of all what do you mean by Java file. Then - what is you final purpose for that you want to serialize/deserialize something?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I'm creating an application on Android Studio and the application is has several features, and you call them through a generator which calls all the methods with specific parameters.  I would like to have the features in an external file so that the applicatin can just read this file and display in function. So this "external file" would be the JSON file that would be deserialized. The deserialization would call all the methods describing the features.

Answer (score -4):

There's two items here. Reading a JSON file, which you can do with a File Stream, and StreamReader. FileReader is an implementation of StreamReader, so that's a decent example below.

https://crunchify.com/how-to-read-json-object-from-file-in-java/

The second point is dynamically calling methods, and yes you are correct, you'd want to use reflection for this. For the below, scroll to the 'Get Class Object' section. Reflection carries with it it's own set of caveats, but it is useful for runtime-scripting. There are other options here though, depending on the complexity of your use case.

The last time I used it in Java was for the interface between a javascript interpreter and my application code, for a game project where I wanted my teammates to be able to script in-game events without requiring a new build for any changes.

https://www.journaldev.com/1789/java-reflection-example-tutorial

EDIT: Answering user's question:
[image: FileReader]

Comment: What is `StreamReader`? And `FileReadsr` is a subclass of `Reader`.

Comment: @user207421 - See the image above.

Comment: See it yourself. No `StreamReader` there.

Comment: 'InputStreamReader' - don't be pedantic

Comment: It's a pedantic profession, by necessity. The compller is pedantic too. Why not fix your answer instead of shooting the messenger?

Comment: No time for trolls here, it's not a pedantic profession if you have a remote understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: @JeremyBensoussan - Please upvote/accept if you used this answer. Trolls are hard at work downvoting.